Multipass VM accessing from local
I am running a flask app on my mac that needs to hit a salt api running on a multipass VM that has ubuntu installed.
Curl call on the virtual machine is returning the output but if I try to access the master using the address https://:8000 from my flask app, there is no entry in the api logs when the app is run.
How do I do this?
